# Interactive map, django

Tags: python, django, image, interactive

I am doing research how to make a website with a map of the world (simple image, not google maps), where I would like to put pins, that will be clickable and redirecting user to the description of those places. I am wondering what is the best way to do this?

My application is written in django and I have no idea what kind of technology should I use?

Comment: Have you tried [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)?

Comment: I guess [image maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) are still a thing, although I haven't seen one in the wild for years.

Comment: Image maps mostly got replaced by svg's and svg utilities. Your question is off-topic however.

Answer (score 3):

I need to track, where some image was clicked, so i use this approach (simplified):
In templates:

```
<a href='/my_view/'><img ismap src='my_map.gif'></a>
```

and in views:

```
def my_view(request):
    (cx,cy)=request.GET.keys()[0].split(',')
    # map was clicked at cx,cy coordinates
    x=int(cx)
    y=int(cy)
    if x>123:
        ........
```